# IEnumerable<XElement> compare is not same

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I read an XML file by following two techniques.

1. By reading the entire XML using Parse XElement `XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText(xmlfile))` 
   Note: I know I shouldn't have used this technique.
2. By using Load of XDocument `XDocument.Load(xmlfile);`

Then I tried creating a list of XElement by the following code snippet. To me, results look same but when I try to compare the two IEnumerable object, they aren't same.

What I am overlooking. Here is the code snippet

```
            // Read the xml db file.
            XElement xEle = XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText(xmlfile));
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);


            List<XElement> xElementCollection = xEle.Elements("Map").ToList();
            List<XElement> xDocumentCollection = xDoc.Descendants("Map").ToList();

            bool bCompare = xElementCollection.Equals(xDocumentCollection);
```

bCompare results to false, however when I look at the data to both the lists. They look same.

Comment: `Equals` is going to do a reference comparison.  You want something that will actually compare the contents of both lists.

Comment: @juharr - what's with all these comment answers tricking me into thinking a question hasn't been answered???

Comment: @hoodaticus but it was not answered. What is that "something" that will perform comparision? Comment gives a clue but does not provide answer.

Comment: xElementCollection is only looking at child elements of the root, while xDocumentCollection is looking at all descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to go through each element in both lists and compare them to each other by value using the XNode.DeepEquals method.

```
if (xElementCollection.Count != xDocumentCollection.Count)
{
  bCompare = false;
}
else
{
   bCompare = true;
   for (int x = 0, y = 0; 
     x < xElementCollection.Count && y < xDocumentCollection.Count; x++, y++)
   {
     if (!XNode.DeepEquals(xElementCollection[x], xDocumentCollection[y]))
       bCompare = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hoodaticus

Comment: @Vivek_Shukla it was a pleasure